# Should I use the Navigation Drawer?

Tags: navigation, android

I have an app in which I would like a slide out menu. It would not be in control of all the apps settings, just a simple menu with a few options. I will still have a settings menu so I don't want to get rid of that. I would like to activate the slide menu with an icon in one of the corners of the app. On the button click I would like to slide out this simple menu (not settings).

Should I use [the Navigation Drawer](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)? My first thought is no, since I am not controlling any sort of navigation from within this slider. Navigation Drawer also has some default behaviors that I am not sure you can override, i.e. slide from left side of screen to access, click app icon to access, click settings menu to access.

Am I supposed to use a Navigation Drawer and try and override a bunch of behavior or is there another Android pattern that I can use?  I.E. if I use a sub menu can I slide that in/out?

Comment: your question is requesting opinions, if you could provide a mockup or wireframe of the app, the answers may prove a bit more objective and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jfeinestien10/SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) I've used it for a number of projects and it's been very flexible to use and effective. This is also the most recommended aside from the stock navigation drawer, and it has allot of adaptability/ functionality for whatever you want it to do.

However sometimes you want something *EVEN MORE* flexible than that; well you're in luck, as far as slidey menu view things go [6wunderkinder/sliding-layer-lib](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib) will 
be the easiest way to try out your crazy next-level interface ideas!